What do you call the food that's in bento boxes when it's homemade?
There's this nice Japanese food in the US that's sold in restaurants under the name bento boxes. It invariably consists of a meat dish (usually sushi or teriyaki), white rice, and a small salad with creamy salad dressing.
I was laid up for a few weeks with one working hand, and realized I could cook this with pre-cut-up beef. The food style appears to me to actually come from Japan and should have a word in Japanese; but bento isn't it. Bento is the name of the package form. (It means something like convenient). I had a hard time explaining what this food was to anybody.
Attached image is the result of me cooking food in the same style as best as I can mimic it.

There are glaring deficiencies in this photo.

The rice is not sticky rice.
The meat should be cut in strips, not this floppy mess.
I used a bagged garden salad.
I hadn't yet learned to dilute the contents of the bottle and cook the meat in it.
I can't eat rice with chopsticks yet, even with ideal preparation.
No soup. I feel the missing-ness of the soup in this one, but I couldn't source any appropriate soup at the local grocery store.

I checked; the local resteraunt does not have a picture; just a description "Miso soup (dine-in only), rice, salad, and 2 different items of your choice to complete your box"; the meat course is cooked essentially the same way no matter which meat. I've gotten essentially the same thing from quite a few restaurants; and they all call it bento as far as I can tell.
I'm after the combined name; otherwise I would just say Teriyaki.

It’s difficult to identify with just "it's a beef dish in a bento box". Do you have a photo?

@naruto: You're in luck. I have a picture.

What you call teriyaki in America is not teriyaki at all.

The specific way in which the beef is sliced is known as 肉絲 in Chinese, and is a telltale of Chinese knife technique, not generally seen in Japanese cooking. I think that might give you a hint about where this kind of item seen in some "Japanese" restaurants in America really comes from.

@jogloran: This is an American pre-sliced beef that I had to use as the starting point. It's not exactly right. A quality restaurant version is half way between this and naruto's photo in shape. To his point, the sauce looks different.

For me teriyaki is either chicken or fish. I've never had or seen "beef teriyaki." More important, teriyaki refers to a particular way of cooking and food thus cooked. Pouring a sauce over any food doesn't make it teriyaki.

@aguijonazo: You practice, you improve. I did in fact learn to cook the meat in the stuff not add it after; but that's the only photo I happen to have. And yes, chicken is more common; but only beef was available pre cut at the store. Everybody is focusing on the details on cooking the meat; I don't think it matters. If I had used chicken the question would be the same. If the rice were missing or the salad were missing I would perceive the nature of the whole differently; likewise if I used a completely different sauce base.

I thought you were asking for a Japanese name, not an American one, since this is a Japanese language forum.

@aguijonazo: I am. I have turned to the apparent origin of the thing and asked for the name and am having a hard time communicating what I am asking. Right now I feel like the Portuguese must have felt when they showed up in India for the first time and asked what a manticore is; when asked to describe it in turn they could produce only bad descriptions. (It's the tiger--the key meaning is "man eater".)

It's not the Indians' fault.

By the way, one reason beef is rarely used must be it's hard to get a smooth surface to "shine." It absorbs the sauce.

This beef dish doesn't look like traditional Japanese food. It doesn't have a specific name, but might generically be described as 細切れ牛肉の炒め物 ("sliced beef stir-fry") or something similar. It doesn't look like typical teriyaki from a Japanese perspective, either.

Most unfortunate. Got a photo of Japanese beef teriyaki I can compare with?

With "beef teriyaki", a Japanese people would imagine something like this, but few of them would think this is a traditional Japanese dish.

I would have guessed not traditional either; but something that came to be in the twentieth century. Nevertheless it appears what I've been getting is something sold in sushi restaurants as a side business because they know some people in a party don't care for sushi.
